# Prevent useState re-rendering Component

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a TextField thats updates state with useState on change. Im facing an issue where upon state change the entire component is re-rendering, I expect only the TextField to change.

```
const Uploader = ({ onUploadComplete }) => {

const [fields, setFields] = useState({});
const handleName = (event) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  setFields((fields) => ({
    ...fields,
    [name]: { value: value },
  }

  <React.Fragment>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
      <Card>{console.log('Card Media Rendered')}</Card>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={8}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <TextField
          value={fields[file.id]?.value || ''}
          onChange={handleName}
        />
      </FormControl>
    </Grid>
  </React.Fragment>
}
```

Comment: A state change causes a component to re-render, that's just how it works.

Comment: Is this the whole component? There seems to be some other issues here as well. Like the fact `Uploader`does not return anything.

Comment: sorry i should of said this code has been trimmed for readibility

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `useState` inside the functional component like this:

```
const Uploader = ({ onUploadComplete }) => {
  const [fields, setFields] = useState({});
  const handleName = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFields((fields) => ({
      ...fields,
      [name]: { value: value },
    }))
  }
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Grid item xs={4}>
        <Card>{console.log('Card Media Rendered')}</Card>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={8}>
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <TextField
            value={fields[file.id]?.value || ''}
            onChange={handleName}
          />
        </FormControl>
      </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Your component did rerender because the variable that it depends on, wasn't in the react scope. So it couldn't trigger the update only to the Textfield

Comment: could you explain further?

Comment: Of course, in the same way you "construct" your state inside a Class component, in the same way you should use the `useState` hook inside a functional component. See here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

React's targeted rerendering works for the dependencies that are inside the context of its components. Meaning that if you use a window variable (not a state variable) inside the render method (or the return of a functional component) it will trigger a rerender to the whole component.

Comment: You can read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: sorry the code was poorly formatted, the usestate is already within component

Comment: How do you check that the component is being rerendered?